# How to create new macro variable from existing macro variables using calculations in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'd like to create a new macro variable from other macro variables that already exist.

I have tried multiple variations of `call symput`, `%eval` , and `input` to no avail...

I would like `d` to evaluate to 3 / 30 = .10.

---

```
*****  taken directly from the sas help files...  ;

%let a=1+2;
%let b=10*3;
%let c=5/3;
%let eval_a=%eval(&a);
%let eval_b=%eval(&b);
%let eval_c=%eval(&c);

%put &a is &eval_a;
%put &b is &eval_b;
%put &c is &eval_c; * not sure why this evaluates to 1, but I'm sure it's documented somewhere... ;


*****  This evaluates to 0...

%let d = %eval(%eval(&a) / %eval(&b)) ; 

%put &d ;
```

---

Thanks so much...

Comment: Why do you want to do math on macro variables?

Comment: Our center uses an old SAS print macro to produce tables for reports.  The tables are sketched out, and then we have to produce them.  Many times, working in a dataset or using data steps works fine, but sometimes it is much faster to produce a value using this method.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Probably preaching to the choir, but if you have the opportunity to modernize, do - SAS tabulation options are 1000x better nowadays than what used to be required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

%eval will only return an integer.  To get the decimal, you need to use %sysevalf.